# Generate Migration for adding new column using rake task in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, rake-task

How can I generate migration to add a column in my existing model using `rake` task in `rails` ?

The following migration should be generate using a `rake` task

```
class AddNameToCustomer < ActiveRecord::Mirgation
  def change
    add_column :customer, :name, :string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace :dummy do
  task test: :environment do
   `rails generate migration AddNameToCustomers name:string`
   sleep 2
   `rake db:migrate`
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi rahul thanks for answer, can i generate migration file that include code of add a column using rake task ?

Comment: You want to add column through rake task, So above code for rake task just create a rake task mentioned above and run it

Comment: actually my main motive is to create a migration file using rake task

Comment: Ok @DineshSaini if you want to create migration file too then you will have to write system command into rake task I have updated my code please have a look

Comment: @DineshSaini : Your welcome. If answer is working fine for you. Please accept this answer and upvote my answer. Thanks!